# Anylogic: Measuring process time without considering waiting time during evening

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have created a discrete simulation model for our production processes in which the capacity, output, etc. should be simulated for the coming year. The model works, but I have a problem with measuring the process time. Our production only works from 7 a.m. to 3 p.m. Is there a way to set the TimeMeasureStart and TimeMeasureEnd block so that the time is only measured during the shift?

As a simplified example with a TimeMeasureStart, a service and a TimeMeasureEnd block:

The agent passes TimeMeasureStart at 2:30 p.m. and immediately enters the service block. The service time is 2 hours. The worker starts the service and goes home at 3:00 p.m. The agent waits in the service block from 3:00 p.m. to 7:00 a.m. At 7 a.m. the worker continues the service (until 8:30 a.m.). As soon as it is finished, the agent passes the TimeMeasureEnd block. The result is currently a process time of 18 hours. However, I only want to measure the time that is worked, so that I get 2 hours as the process time.

Is there a possibility to set / program the TimeMeasureStart / TimeMeasureEnd blocks accordingly so that the waiting time is not included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion would be to ensure that you really need calendar time, why not just run the model in hours and every hour is a working hour... then you don't need to shift schedule.

But often for reporting or having different shift patterns within your model requires you to need calendar time as the basis.

Here is a simple solution: Simply record the time a resource was seized through your own local variables.

You need to add two double variables to your agent 1 for last start and 1 for the cumulative time
`previousServiceStart` and `cummServiceTime`

and then save the times in the resource pool using the `On seize` and `On release` code

[image]

I casted the agent to my custom agent using the `(MyAgent)agent` code, so that I can access the variables